# Euler angles discrepancy in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, rotational-matrices

I have a rotation matrix from one basis to another:

```
 Rot = [0.1227    0.0269   -0.9921;...
        0.8635   -0.4956    0.0934;...
        0.4892    0.8681    0.0840];
```

I use MATLAB `rotm2eul` function to get the Euler angles in 'ZYZ' convention:

```
eulZYZ = rotm2eul(Rot,"ZYZ")
```

which is  `-0.0938   -1.4867   -1.0577`. If I use the inverse function `eul2rotm`:

```
RotMATLAB = eul2rotm(eulZYZ,"ZYZ");
```

the result is different from `Rot` (except the third column):

```
RotMATLAB =
   -0.0406    0.1189   -0.9921
   -0.8712    0.4819    0.0934
    0.4892    0.8681    0.0840
```

What is going on? I thought that once you specified the 'ZYZ' there exists only one rotation.

Comment: i don't believe `rotm2eul` is a part of Octave or any package of which I'm aware.  Is there a reason this is tagged Octave? If it's available where? and does it behave the same in this case?

Comment: it was my naive assumption, removed it, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rotation matrices generally are assumed to have determinant `1`, but your "rotation" matrix `Rot` has determinant `det(Rot) = -1`, which means that your matrix also contains a (odd) number of reflections, not only rotations.

So there is no hope for `rotm2eul` to produce any meaningful output for this matrix. Try  doing the same by e.g. first multiplying your own matrix by a reflection matrix to ensure that `Rot` has determinant `1`, like

```
 diag([1,1,-1])
```